# How to display loader before view to be rendered is decided?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am working on a laravel app. There is a controller which returns a certain view if all the required validations are passed. Form loading is really slow as it takes a lot of time to validate and fetch the data required for the form. The code and DB is not much optimized and we are already working on it but we need to buy some time for optimization by instantly adding a loader unless form is rendered to improve customer experience.

Now the issue is that the view to be rendered is not decided unless the validation passes. How can i add a loader in this situation in the shortest time?

One of my colleague suggested to first return a loader view containing ajax call to the actual form rendering code. In this way, the loader will appear until the form HTML is returned and set but I am not sure how the performance will be impacted by this? Is this a right way?

Please note that I cant change the URL of the form as it is distributed via email

Comment: For now this is handled by submitting a classic HTML form with a *submit button* without any JS handling?

Comment: "Is this a right way?" - that might be one, but it depends on your use case. Why not try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX here. While you are proccessing data a loader can be used. After getting success from Ajax you can hide your previous view using javascript and CSS. and show the new data or redirect the user to a different route.

```
//start_loader
$.ajax({
  url: '{{ route('your_route_name') }}',
  method: 'POST',
  data: your_data_object,
  success: function(data) {
    //end loader
    location.href = 'redirect_here'
  },
  error: function(data) {
    //end loader
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```